# Why does process substitution streams can be read only once in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Here's a script I wrote to illustrate the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat_then_tac()
{
    echo cat
    cat "$1"
    echo tac
    tac "$1"
    echo end
}

seq 3 > file1

echo
echo using proper file: works as expected
cat_then_tac file1

echo
echo using process substitution: stream is somehow consumed upon first use and tac has nothing to work on
cat_then_tac <(seq 3)

rm file1
```

And here's its output:

```
using proper file: works as expected
cat
1
2
3
tac
3
2
1
end

using process substitution: stream is somehow consumed upon first use and tac has nothing to work on
cat
1
2
3
tac
end
```

Obviously one can work around this by first saving the stream (in a file or variable) and using it as many times as needed. But why does this sort of consumption happen?

---

Later, I found this question on Unix-StackExchange related to the same matter. And it also contains info worth taking a look:
[Bash Reuse Process Substitution File](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18467/bash-reuse-process-substitution-file)

Comment: You can process stdin only once as well. Why do you think that process substitution should be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process substitution is implemented using pipes. The output of the substituted process is buffered by the operating system and discarded after it is read. So `cat_then_tac <(seq 3)` is the same as

```
seq 3 | cat_then_tac -
```